# How do I store data in downstream when connected to federation?

Tags: volttron

I connected VOLTTRON instances using Rabbitmq's federation.

The transfer of data from upstream to downstream was confirmed using the listener agent.

However, the historian of volttron (downstream) does not store the forwarded data.

Since the data collected directly from the volttron (downstream) is stored, historian has confirmed that it operates normally.

How do I store the data passed to federation?

ver: develop

tested historian: influx, sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the topics to which the historian’s data is getting published. Currently historian only record data published to devices/*, datalogger/*, analysis/*, record/*

There is PR https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/pull/1964 that is currently under review which would enable configuring custom topics for historians. This should get merged in the near future and might be helpful for your use case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
However, I tested using the fake device on the master driver.
In other words, the topic starts with 'devices /'.

Comment: Historian is unaware of source. As long as the message ends up on its local message bus and the subscription match it should store the data in the database. To confirm -- You have a historian and listener downstream, you are running master driver and fake device on upstream. The listener agent on the downstream confirms that the data published from upstream ends up on the downstream message bus, but the data does not get into db? Have you tried stopping master driver upstream. Install master driver downstream to confirm if the data gets in & if topic name match between upstream and downstream?

Comment: I tested both cases.

1st case is (Downstream: listener, sqlhistorian) + (Upstream: master driver with fake device)

Downstream listener subscribed to upstream data well.
But historian could not save the data.


2st case is (Downstream: listener, sqlhistorian, master driver with fake device)

In this case, the listener subscribes well to the data and the historian stores the data well.

I guess one thing.
If you do not set 'all_platform' to true when subscribing, the listener will not be able to subscribe to upstream data.
I guess that the same problem will arise in the historian